# Searching for a » character in a JavaScript RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I search for a » character in a JavaScript regexp?

Code that's not working right now:

```
var extralinks = new RegExp('»','g');  
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.replace(extralinks,'This is special punctuation');
```

Grazie!

Comment: Is this as a plain character or as a character reference in the HTML code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

var extraLinks = /\xBB/g;

Answer (score 0):

look up the ASCII table and escape the character http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: I guess the question is - how do I escape it?  I've looked up the representation for the right double angle quotes.  Options: Hex BB, HTML number &#187; HTML name &raquo;.  But how to tell Javascript that this is a hex representation of a character and not just the characters BB?